# Is there a way to get rid of misordered 'duplicates' if you don't care about the column name?

Tags: python, sql

Say I have the below table.

| Alpha | B1 | B2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cow | Dog |
| 1 | Dog | Cow |
| 2 | Cat | Pig |
| 2 | Cat | Hen |
| 2 | Hen | Cat |
| 2 | Pig | Cat |
| 3 | Cow | Dog |
| 3 | Dog | Cow |

I want to say that B1 and B2 are interchangeable in function, and that order does not matter. That is to say, the first two rows are equivalent because it contains 'Dog' and 'Cow' for my B columns. As a result, I want to delete one of them to get rid of duplicates, essentially looking like the below table.

| Alpha | B1 | B2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cow | Dog |
| 2 | Cat | Pig |
| 2 | Cat | Hen |
| 3 | Dog | Cow |

I'm a bit stumped here, because I think I would start with a For loop, but I am not sure how to best make the different rows 'talk' to each other. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to delete the rows in the database? Or delete after selection?

Comment: After selection -- or to select only one of each combo of rows.

Comment: @AStackz, Which database? and looking for SQL or python code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Arun had a pretty good writeup on how to do it. I was mostly stuck on a way to make it order-agnostic: that is, B1 and B2 show the same info, and yet Cow-Dog is counted differently from Dog-Cow. I wanted a way to show that they were the same thing, and therefore be able to get rid of the 'duplicates.'

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can achieve this using *pandas* (you can customize this strategy as per your platform/tech):

Firstly, Creating a sorted & concatenated column based on `B1` and `B2`. Since we are sorting first, both Cow, Dog and Dog, Cow will now become `Cow-Dog`:

```
df['concat'] = ['-'.join(sorted(tup)) for tup in zip(df['B1'], df['B2'])]
    
#dropping B1 and B2 because they will mess up the level of data
df_new = df.drop(['B1','B2'], 1)
```

Now, we will end up with having duplicate rows. Hence dropping them:

```
pre = df_new.drop_duplicates(subset=['Alpha', 'concat'], keep="first")
```

Job done! Now expanding concatenated column back to original shape (B1 and B2) and dropping Concatenated column:

```
pre[['B1','B2']] = pre.concat.str.split("-",expand=True,)
final = pre.drop(['concat'], 1)
```

`Final` dataframe will contain your desired output!

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate this! I was trying to figure out a way to make it agnostic of order, but I had a feeling SQL wasn't up to the task. Python is definitely something that I'll have to go over again, considering that being able to store lists or tuples as a single variable is going to be a powerful thing.

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to catch your point. Are you looking for a solution in SQL?

Comment: No, not strictly within SQL. I was making conversation and noting that being able to store a list (the contents of B1 and B2) in Python is pretty helpful compared to SQL!

Comment: True that! Python always be the savior. Kindly accept and upvote if my answer was useful.

Comment: I tried, but don't have the rep for that. :(

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped you :).